# invalid operation exception when I calling web service Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

I try calling web service. I add reference to web service in Visual Studio https://gate.smsclub.mobi/soap/soapGateway.wsdl and I try calling method from this service I have exception (exception on this screenshot) http://s020.radikal.ru/i709/1510/a6/32a6d38ecf7a.png
My code :

```
smsGatewayPortTypeClient sms = new smsGatewayPortTypeClient("smsGatewayPort");
```

app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="smsGatewayBinding" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://gate.smsclub.mobi/soap/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="smsGatewayBinding" contract="ServiceReference1.smsGatewayPortType"
            name="smsGatewayPort" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: @anekcahap Can you take a screenshot of error in English

Comment: Exception type "System.InvalidOperationException" appeared in System.ServiceModel.dll, but it was not handled in user code

For more information: Could not find endpoint element with name "smsGatewayPort" and contract "ServiceReference1.smsGatewayPortType" section Client Configuration

Comment: Refer this [Link](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2008/11/26/reading-wcf-configuration-from-a-custom-location.aspx/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all! I solved my problem other method. In Visual Studio click add service reference -> Advanced -> Add service reference and past link on web service after I calling method and it works

Answer (score 0):

We need to do it manually. This [Link](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2008/11/26/reading-wcf-configuration-from-a-custom-location.aspx/) will tell how  to load the config manually and create a `CustomChannelFactory<>` to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

use contract="smsGatewayPortType" instead of contract="ServiceReference1.smsGatewayPortType"

Answer (score 0):

The awnser from Александр Тур helped me.

I had the System.InvalidOperationException too when i tried my self made Web Service in Visual Studio.

in VS2017 you have to go to:

> Project -> Add Service Reference... -> Advanced... -> Add Web Reference...

there you have to **put the URL** of your Web Service and under **Web reference name** you can Change the name and then **Click Add Reference**

you can then use our WebService like This:

```
referenceName.WebService1 ws = new referenceName.WebService1();
ws.doThingsMethod();
```